Uniform distribution problem involving two buses
I am trying to solve the following problem:
A bus on line A arrives at a bus station every 4 minutes and a bus on line B every 6 minutes. The time interval between an arrival of a bus for line A and a bus for line B is uniformly distributed between 0 and 4 minutes. Find the probability:
a) That the first bus that arrives will be for line A.
b) That a bus will arrive within 2 minutes (for line A or B).
But I do not know how to incorporate the given information.
I understand that the random variable $X$ having a uniform distribution here is the timelapse between an arrival of a bus for line A and a bus for line B. But then, how can I translate it to solve item a) and b)?
For example, if I do $F_X(2)$ which is the probability that both buses are apart for at least 2 minutes, how is it related to which one arrives first, or within a certain amount of time?
--
EDIT 1: As suggested, I typed in the question instead of the image from the book I had before.

Hi! It will help future search queries if you actually type in the question. It shouldn't take long, and it helps other users. You can retain the link to the original image if you want.

@BrianTung Thanks for the advice.

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.
